# Show percent % instead of counts in charts of categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a categorical variable and instead of showing the counts for each category value.

I'm looking for a way to get `ggplot` to display the percentage of values in that category. Of course, it is possible to create another variable with the calculated percentage and plot that one, but I have to do it several dozens of times and I hope to achieve that in one command.

I was experimenting with something like

```
qplot(mydataf) +
  stat_bin(aes(n = nrow(mydataf), y = ..count../n)) +
  scale_y_continuous(formatter = "percent")
```

but I must be using it incorrectly, as I got errors.

To easily reproduce the setup, here's a simplified example:

```
mydata <- c ("aa", "bb", NULL, "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "ee", NULL, "cc");
mydataf <- factor(mydata);
qplot (mydataf); #this shows the count, I'm looking to see % displayed.
```

In the real case, I'll probably use `ggplot` instead of `qplot`, but the right way to use [stat_bin](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_bin.html) still eludes me.

I've also tried these four approaches:

```
ggplot(mydataf, aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(formatter = 'percent');

ggplot(mydataf, aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(formatter = 'percent') + geom_bar();

ggplot(mydataf, aes(x = levels(mydataf), y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(formatter = 'percent');

ggplot(mydataf, aes(x = levels(mydataf), y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(formatter = 'percent') + geom_bar();
```

but all 4 give:

> ```
> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor
> ```

The same error appears for the simple case of

```
ggplot (data=mydataf, aes(levels(mydataf))) +
  geom_bar()
```

so it's clearly something about how `ggplot` interacts with a single vector. I'm scratching my head, googling for that error gives a single [result](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/0489a702f3afc83b).

Comment: Data should be a data frame, not a bare factor.

Comment: adding to hadley's comment, converting your data into a data frame using mydataf = data.frame(mydataf), and renaming it as names(mydataf) = foo will do the trick

Answer (score 255, accepted):

Since this was answered there have been some meaningful changes to the `ggplot` syntax.  Summing up the discussion in the comments above:

```
 require(ggplot2)
 require(scales)

 p <- ggplot(mydataf, aes(x = foo)) +  
        geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
        ## version 3.0.0
        scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

Here's a reproducible example using `mtcars`:

```
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(hp))) +  
        geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
        scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) ## version 3.0.0
```

[image]

This question is currently the #1 hit on google for 'ggplot count vs percentage histogram' so hopefully this helps distill all the information currently housed in comments on the accepted answer.

**Remark:** If `hp` is not set as a factor, ggplot returns:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Any idea on how to do it class-wise ?

Comment: As .@WAF suggests, this answer does not work with faceted data.  See @Erwan's comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181132/normalizing-y-axis-in-histograms-in-r-ggplot-to-proportion-by-group?lq=1

Comment: You might need to prefix `percent` with the package it's from to get the above to work (I did).

 `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(hp))) +  
        geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)`

Comment: To get around use of facets use `geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..]))` instead. Each facet should sum to 100%.

Comment: Wasn't variables with ".." around them replaced with the stat()-command? https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat.html

Comment: Can you use stat() to to something similar?

Comment: @Magnus, see my new answer, using the newer `after_stat()` function.

Comment: @mammykins Is there any simple solution for faceted data then? The link was not useful

Comment: @stragu Link of your answer?

Comment: @Julien: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66095887/1494531

Answer (score 58):

this modified code should work

```
p = ggplot(mydataf, aes(x = foo)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
    scale_y_continuous(formatter = 'percent')
```

if your data has NAs and you dont want them to be included in the plot, pass na.omit(mydataf) as the argument to ggplot.

hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it and get "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class factor". By the way, if there's only one vector of values, what would be instead of 'foo'? I don't have column labels.

Comment: see my comment after hadley's comment.

Comment: minor correction: the second command suggested, should have had quotes around "foo": names(mydataf) = "foo". With this and with data.frame() call, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in ggplot2 version 0.9.0 the `formatter` argument will no longer work. Instead, you'll want something like `labels = percent_format())`.

Comment: And with 0.9.0 you'll need to load the `scales` library before using `percent_format()`, otherwise it won't work. 0.9.0 doesn't automatically load supporting packages anymore.

Comment: Note that `na.omit` will omit all rows with an `NA` in any column, even columns unrelated to your plot.

Comment: Can someone point me to an explanation/documentation how the "..count.." stuff works, please? I haven't found it the docs.

Comment: See `? stat_bin`. It shows what additional columns are added to the data frame by `ggplot2`. All extra columns are of the form `..variable..`.

Comment: Does it make sense to replace `aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))` with simply `aes(y = ..density..)`? Visually it give very similar (but still different) picture

Comment: In ggplot 0.9.3.1.0, you'll want to first load the `scales` library, then use `scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)` as mentioned [in the docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html#)

Comment: Note that if you actually want percents, not fractions, you will need to use something like `geom_bar(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..))*100))`

Comment: @Ramnath, I was trying to use the above code with fill = "another categorical variable", I get the plot but the % on y axis and bar height is not as per the actual percentage for the bar, instead it seems it is taking combination of the fill variable and then showing the height. How can I correct this? Can help by suggesting a solution. I have posted the problem at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078480/r-shiny-ggplot-bar-and-line-charts-with-dynamic-variable-selection-and-y-axis-to

Comment: For those coming to this after 2018, replace "labels = percent_format()" with "labels = scales::percent"

Answer (score 53):

With ggplot2 version 2.1.0 it is

```
+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: Does not display the right percentages with facets

Answer (score 47):

As of March 2017, with `ggplot2` 2.2.1 I think the best solution is explained in Hadley Wickham's R for data science book:

```
ggplot(mydataf) + stat_count(mapping = aes(x=foo, y=..prop.., group=1))
```

`stat_count` computes two variables: `count` is used by default, but you can choose to use `prop` which shows proportions.

Comment: This is the best answer as of June 2017, works with filling by group and with faceting.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't allow me to use the `fill` mapping (no error is thrown, but no fill color is added).

Comment: @MaxCandocia I had to remove `group = 1` in order to get fill mapping. maybe it helps

Comment: If I remove the `group` parameter, though, it does not show the proper percentages, since everything belongs to its own group for each unique x value.

Answer (score 27):

If you want percentages on the y-axis *and* labeled on the bars:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  labs(title = "Manual vs. Automatic Frequency", y = "Percent", x = "Automatic Transmission")
```

[image]

When adding the bar labels, you may wish to omit the y-axis for a cleaner chart, by adding to the end:

```
  theme(
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Note that if your variable is continuous, you will have to use geom_histogram(), as the function will group the variable by "bins".

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = rnorm(100))

ggplot(df, aes(x = V1)) +  
  geom_histogram(aes(y = 100*(..count..)/sum(..count..))) 

# if you use geom_bar(), with factor(V1), each value of V1 will be treated as a
# different category. In this case this does not make sense, as the variable is 
# really continuous. With the hp variable of the mtcars (see previous answer), it 
# worked well since hp was not really continuous (check unique(mtcars$hp)), and one 
# can want to see each value of this variable, and not to group it in bins.
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(V1))) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))
```

Comment: Great solution. But you forgot to multiply by 100 to get %, i.e. `geom_histogram(aes(y = 100*(..count..)/sum(..count..)))`.

Comment: `+scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())` to display in nice percent format

Answer (score 9):

Since [version 3.3 of ggplot2](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#more-control-over-aesthetic-evaluation), we have access to the convenient `after_stat()` function.

We can do something similar to @Andrew's answer, but without using the `..` syntax:

```r
# original example data
mydata <- c("aa", "bb", NULL, "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "ee", NULL, "cc")

# display percentages
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = mydata,
                     y = after_stat(count/sum(count)))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

You can find all the "computed variables" available to use in the documentation of the `geom_` and `stat_` functions. For example, for `geom_bar()`, you can access the `count` and `prop` variables. (See the [documentation for computed variables](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html?q=geom%20_%20bar#computed-variables).)

One comment about your `NULL` values: they are ignored when you create the vector (i.e. you end up with a vector of length 9, not 11). If you really want to keep track of missing data, you will have to use `NA` instead (ggplot2 will put NAs at the right end of the plot):

```r
# use NA instead of NULL
mydata <- c("aa", "bb", NA, "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "aa", "ee", NA, "cc")
length(mydata)
#> [1] 11

# display percentages
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = mydata,
                     y = after_stat(count/sum(count)))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

(Note that using `chr` or `fct` data will not make a difference for your example.)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a workaround for faceted data. (The accepted answer by @Andrew does not work in this case.) The idea is to calculate the percentage value using dplyr and then to use geom_col to create the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

binwidth <- 30

mtcars.stats <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(bin = cut(hp, breaks=seq(0,400, binwidth), 
               labels= seq(0+binwidth,400, binwidth)-(binwidth/2)),
         n = n()) %>%
  group_by(cyl, bin) %>%
  summarise(p = n()/n[1]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(bin = as.numeric(as.character(bin)))

ggplot(mtcars.stats, aes(x = bin, y= p)) +  
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  facet_grid(cyl~.)
```

This is the plot:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want percentage *labels* but actual Ns on the y axis, try this:

```
    library(scales)
perbar=function(xx){
      q=ggplot(data=data.frame(xx),aes(x=xx))+
      geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)),fill="orange")
       q=q+    geom_text(aes(y = (..count..),label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="bin",colour="darkgreen") 
      q
    }
    perbar(mtcars$disp)
```