# ggplot2: sorting a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame, that is sorted from highest to lowest. For example:

```
x <- structure(list(variable = structure(c(10L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 
9L, 5L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), value = c(0.990683229813665, 
0.975155279503106, 0.928571428571429, 0.807453416149068, 0.717391304347826, 
0.388198757763975, 0.357142857142857, 0.201863354037267, 0.173913043478261, 
0.0496894409937888)), .Names = c("variable", "value"), row.names = c(10L, 
6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 7L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(x, aes(x=variable,y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
 scale_y_continuous("",label=scales::percent) + coord_flip()
```

Now, the data is nice and sorted, but when I plot, it comes out sorted by factor. It's annoying, how do I fix it?

Comment: With R version 3.2.2, I get an error: `scale_y_continuous("", formatter = "percent") :  unused argument (formatter = "percent")`

Comment: Yes, I beleive its `scale_y_continuos(labels=percent)` and you must also load the `scales` package.

Comment: Then I have a new error  `Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways.

The first will order things based on the order seen in the data frame:

```
x$variable <- factor(x$variable, levels=unique(as.character(x$variable)) )
```

The second orders the levels based on another variable (value in this case):

```
x <- transform(x, variable=reorder(variable, -value) )
```

Comment: The second one consitently provided the result I was looking for without the "-".

Comment: reorder() will be overwritten by the gdata package. If you're at a loss for why it's not working, this could be why.

Comment: I wish ggplot2 would be rewritten to make it little easier. I already sort my data.frame and why the order is not respected by the plot....

Answer (score 89):

This seems to be what you're looking for:

```
g <- ggplot(x, aes(reorder(variable, value), value))
g + geom_bar() + scale_y_continuous(formatter="percent") + coord_flip()
```

The `reorder()` function will reorder your x axis items according to the `value` of `variable`.

Comment: Would be good to add an explanation of what this is supposed to do.

Comment: In case someone is having issues with the `formatter=` argument: this has changed to `labels = scales::percent` in more recent versions (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14511974/2761742).

Comment: What does this do when there are multiple groups?

Comment: Unfortunately the x-labels are now numeric, and not the variable's values.

Answer (score 11):

I've recently been struggling with a related issue, discussed at length here: [Order of legend entries in ggplot2 barplots with coord_flip()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299440/ordering-variables-by-groups-in-ggplot2-barplots-with-coord-flip) .

As it happens, the reason I had a hard time explaining my issue clearly, involved the relation between (the order of) factors and coord_flip(), as seems to be the case here.

I get the desired result by adding `+  xlim(rev(levels(x$variable)))` to the ggplot statement:

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=variable,y=value)) + geom_bar() + 
scale_y_continuous("",formatter="percent") + coord_flip() 
+  xlim(rev(levels(x$variable)))
```

This reverses the order of factors **as found in the original data frame** in the x-axis, which will become the y-axis with coord_flip(). Notice that in this particular example, the variable also happen to be in alphabetical order, but specifying an arbitrary order of levels within `xlim()` should work in general.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why this question was reopened but here is a `tidyverse` option.

```
x %>% 
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  mutate(variable=fct_reorder(variable,value)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(variable,value,fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous("",label=scales::percent) + coord_flip()
```

Comment: It wasn't reopened. Someone update the parameter arguments to reflect changes to ggplot2 since 2010 :)

Comment: Isn't it that `geom_bar(stat="identity")   = geom_col()`?

Comment: @JabroJacob [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008974/why-is-stat-identity-necessary-in-geom-bar-in-ggplot) but not sure why you asked since OP used stat identity and just needed a sorted plot.

Comment: Just to hint that it can be used instead

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the x-factor into an `ordered` factor with the ordering you want, e.g

```
x <- data.frame("variable"=letters[1:5], "value"=rnorm(5)) ## example data
x <- x[with(x,order(-value)), ] ## Sorting
x$variable <- ordered(x$variable, levels=levels(x$variable)[unclass(x$variable)])

ggplot(x, aes(x=variable,y=value)) + geom_bar() +
   scale_y_continuous("",formatter="percent") + coord_flip()
```

I don't know any better way to do the ordering operation.  What I have there will only work if there are no duplicate levels for `x$variable`.

Comment: This works for the example I have provided, but it doesn't seem to translate for my actual problem.

Comment: I've changed the example to provide actual data that I'm working with

Comment: It doesn't need to be an _ordered_ factor - it just needs to be a factor with the right order.