# how to sort the string vector in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

The string vector in R is such as:

```
C1 C2 C3 ... C10 C11 ... C16
```

But when I use this vector as x labels in plot I got

```
C1 C10 C11 ... C16 C2 C3 ... C9
```

How can I sort the string vector as the original series?

My code is:

```
tension <- read.table(file="targettension.txt")
t.frame <- data.frame(number = factor(paste(rep("C",16),(1:16),sep="")),tension = tension)
p <- ggplot(t.frame,aes(x=number,y=tension)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") 
p + geom_text(aes(label=tension),just=1.5,colour="white",size=3,angle=90)
```

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744178/ggplot2-sorting-a-plot) .  As in the link, use the `levels` argument in 'factor' to keep the order you wanted.

Comment: you can sort character vectors like this with `gtools::mixedsort(paste0('C', 1:16))` also but like akrun says you will still have to give the levels when converting to factor

Comment: The problem is solved as you advised. Thank you very much! @akrun

Comment: @rawr Thank you for your answer. I'll try your method latter.