# Reversed order after coord_flip in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes

Data example from dbv:

```
  gender Sektion
1      m       5
2      m       5
3      w      3B
4      w      3B
5      w      3B
6      m       4
```

I have the following plot:

```
Sekplot <- ggplot(dbv,aes(x=Sektion,
                          fill=factor(gender),
                          stat="bin", 
                          label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%"))) 
Sekplot <- Sekplot + geom_bar(position="fill")
Sekplot <- Sekplot + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
Sekplot <- Sekplot + labs(title = "test")
Sekplot <- Sekplot + scale_fill_discrete(name="test", breaks=c("m", "w", "k.A."), labels=c("m", "w", "k.A."))
Sekplot <- Sekplot + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = ges, linetype = "test"), colour = "black", size = 0.75, show_guide = T)
Sekplot <- last_plot() + coord_flip()
Sekplot <- Sekplot + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0 )), 
                                    fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0 )), 
                                    shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0 )), 
                                    linetype = guide_legend()) + theme(legend.title=element_blank())

Sekplot
```

Output: Plot with y-axis in wrong order

[image: Plot with y-axis in wrong order]

How can I reverse the order of the "Sektion" axis? I'd like to have one on top and 8 at the bottom.

I tried, according to `groupA$Date <- factor(groupA$Date, levels=rev(unique(groupA$Date)))`:

```
Sekplot <- last_plot() + coord_flip() + scale_x_reverse()
```

in several flavor, but couldn't find the right way.

Comment: You need something like `scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dat$Sektion)))` - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7310754/2461552)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm! I cannot mark this question as solved, because the answer is in a comment.

Comment: I hadn't put it as an answer because I was trying to find duplicates.  I haven't found a really good match, though, so will add as answer.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can add `scale_x_discrete` with the `limits` argument to do this.  You could simply write out the limits in the order you want, but that gets complicated when you have many factor levels.

Instead, you can pull the levels of the factor from your dataset and take advantage of `rev` to put them in reverse order.

It would look like:

```
scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dbv$Sektion)))
```

**2022 edit by @slhck**

Adding in example using `forcats::fct_rev()` function to set the levels of the factor in reverse order. You can either make this change in the dataset or use directly when mapping your `x` variable as below.

```
ggplot(dbv, aes(x = forcats::fct_rev(Sektion),
               fill = factor(gender),
               stat = "bin", 
               label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")
   )
)
...
```

Comment: `forcats::fct_rev()` is useful here.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @sindri_baldur, while you're specifying the aesthetics, add fct_rev() like so `ggplot(dbv,aes(x=fct_rev(Sektion), fill=factor(gender),stat="bin", label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")))`

That should be all you need ... remove the `scale_x_discrete()` from your code.