# percentage on y lab in a faceted ggplot barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

doing facets in ggplot I would often like the percentage to be used instead of counts.

e.g.

```
test1 <- sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace=T)
test2 <- sample(letters[3:8], 100, replace=T)
test <- data.frame(cbind(test1,test2))
ggplot(test, aes(test2))+geom_bar()+facet_grid(~test1)
```

This is very easy but if N is different in facet A compared to facet B, it would be better I think, to compare percentages, in such a way that the each facet sums to 100%.

how would you achieve this?

Hope my question makes sense.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
# first make a dataframe with frequencies
df <- as.data.frame(with(test, table(test1,test2)))
# or with count() from plyr package as Hadley suggested
df <- count(test, vars=c('test1', 'test2'))
# next: compute percentages per group
df <- ddply(df, .(test1), transform, p = Freq/sum(Freq))
# and plot
ggplot(df, aes(test2, p))+geom_bar()+facet_grid(~test1)
```

[image]

You could also add `+ scale_y_continuous(formatter = "percent")` to the plot for **ggplot2** version 0.8.9, or `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())` for version 0.9.0.

Comment: This is a much better solution. +1

Comment: @Chase and @Andreas: thank you! I have just posted a simpler (and I think: nicer) method based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3695497/564164

Comment: Try using `count` instead of `as.data.frame(table(...))` - it's much faster and doesn't turn all tabulating variables into factors.

Comment: @hadley: thank you for pointing my attention to this useful function. I made a note of it for the future!

Comment: For ggplot2 v.1.0.1, that last part needs to be:   `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)`

Answer (score 55):

Here is a within `ggplot` method, using `..count..` and `..PANEL..`:

```
ggplot(test, aes(test2)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..])) + 
    facet_grid(~test1)
```

As this is computed on the fly, it should be robust to changes to plot parameters.

Comment: This is a great approach. Do you think it's posible to add percentage labels to each bar that add to 100% in each facet?

Comment: @MartínBel It seems that `geom_text` doesn't work with computed variables. You might want to post as a separate question.

Comment: Sure. Here is the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600900/r-faceted-bar-chart-with-percentages-labels-independent-for-each-plot) I leave it here for future reference.

Comment: so very helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: If using stat='identity', then `..y../tapply(..y.., ..PANEL.., sum)[..PANEL..]` works.

Answer (score 8):

A very simple way:

```
ggplot(test, aes(test2)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
    facet_grid(~test1)
```

So I only changed the parameter of geom_bar to `aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))`.
 After setting ylab to NULL and specifying the formatter, you could get:

```
ggplot(test, aes(test2)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
    facet_grid(~test1) +
    scale_y_continuous('', formatter="percent")
```

**Update** 
Note that while `formatter = "percent")` works for **ggplot2** version 0.8.9, in 0.9.0 you'd want something like `scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())`.
[image]

Comment: ghezus - I actually think somebody on SO answered this for me before. Embarrising for me - hopefully this will come up in search's from now on. Thanks again.

Comment: actually is scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) (using the scales package)

Comment: can someone help me understand the meaning of ..  in the above statement (..count..)/sum(..count..) ??

Comment: @Abhi - it's an internal ggplot2 function: "To use these variables in an aesthetic mapping, you need to surrond them with .., like aes(x = ..output..). This tells ggplot that the variable isn't the original dataset, but has been created by the statistic." see: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_sum.html

Comment: This will make the percentages add to 100 for the whole plot , not for each facet. Maybe something new in latests version of ggplot2

Comment: In version 0.9.3 of ggplot2 this does not work. Instead of adding up each facet to 100%, this adds *all* facets to 100%.

Comment: My previous comment is incorrect. I am seeing a very strange behavior: starting from a fresh R session, this works. Starting within a project that loads a whole bunch of libraries, this does not work. Instead of adding up each facet to 100%, this adds *all* facets to 100%. Looks like a bug in ggplot2--something is getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that should get you moving in the right direction. I'm curious to see if there are more efficient ways to go about doing this as this seems a bit hacky and convoluted. We can use the built in `..density..` argument for the `y aesthetic`, but factors don't work there. So we also need to use `scale_x_discrete` to appropriately label the axis once we converted `test2` into a numeric object.

```
ggplot(data = test, aes(x = as.numeric(test2)))+ 
geom_bar(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = .5)+ 
scale_x_discrete(limits = sort(unique(test$test2))) + 
facet_grid(~test1) + xlab("Test 2") + ylab("Density")
```

But give this a whirl and let me know what you think.

Also, you can shorten your test data creation like so, which avoids the extra objects in your environment and having to cbind them together:

```
test <- data.frame(
    test1 = sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE), 
    test2 = sample(letters[3:8], 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Comment: yeah a bit convoluted - but still thanks - better then what I had :-) I don't know if this should be a feature of ggplot. I could imagine many situations where it would be better then plottng counts. On the other hand - it might be best to keep data mungering af graphing seperate :-)

Comment: Density is not the same as percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for sharing the PANEL "tip" on the `ggplot` method.

For information: you can produce percentages in `y lab`, on the same bar chart, by using `count` and `group` in the `ggplot` method:

```
ggplot(test, aes(test2,fill=test1))
   + geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/tapply(..count..,..group..,sum)[..group..]), position="dodge")
   + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

Comment: Whilst others may feel that this would perhaps be better suited as a comment and not an answer, I gave this answer a +1 because it helped me solve a problem I was having and wanted to thank Lilly for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

I deal with similar situations quite frequently, but take a very different approach that uses two of Hadley's other packages, namely reshape and plyr. Primarily because I have a preference for looking at things as 100% stacked bars (when they total to 100%).

```
test <- data.frame(sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace=T), sample(letters[3:8], 100, replace=T))
colnames(test) <- c("variable","value")
test <- cast(test, variable + value ~ .) 
colnames(test)[3] <- "frequ"

test <- ddply(test,"variable", function(x) {
    x <- x[order(x$value),]
    x$cfreq <- cumsum(x$frequ)/sum(x$frequ)
    x$pos <- (c(0,x$cfreq[-nrow(x)])+x$cfreq)/2
    x$freq <- (x$frequ)/sum(x$frequ)
    x
})

plot.tmp <- ggplot(test, aes(variable,frequ, fill=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="fill") + coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous("", formatter="percent")
```