# Sum percentages for each facet - respect "fill"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a faceted barplot, with percentages adding up to 100 for each facet. The solution to this seems to be a combination of `group` and `..density..`. How ever - it seems to me that `group`is conflicting with `fill`.

Data:

```
test <- data.frame(
     test1 = sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE), 
     test2 = sample(letters[3:8], 100, replace = TRUE)
 )
```

This gets the percentages right:

```
ggplot(test, aes(test2)) +
     geom_bar(aes(y = ..density.., fill=test2,group=test1)) + 
     facet_grid(~test1)
```

Bus as you can see, `fill`is overwritten:
[image: percentage sums to 100 for each facet]

However, the code below respects `fill` but gives me the wrong percentages (sums to 100 for the whole chart)(using ..density..):

```
ggplot(test, aes(test2)) +
     geom_bar(aes(y = ..count../sum(..count..), fill=test2)) + 
     facet_grid(~test1)
```

[image: percentage sums to 100 for the total chart]

Related: This old question of mine: [percentage on y lab in a faceted ggplot barchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725339/percentage-on-y-lab-in-a-faceted-ggplot-barchart).

And yes - I could create additional data, but I feel this belongs in the presentation layer. Actually this feels like a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but you can reference `..x..` within the `geom_bar` call. The only problem is that `ggplot` considers this  `numeric` and so I have coerced to factor and given nice labels within a  call to `scale_fill_brewer`

```
ggplot(test, aes(x= test2, group = test1)) + 
   geom_bar(aes(y = ..density.., fill = factor(..x..))) + 
   facet_grid(~test1) + 
   scale_fill_brewer(name = 'test2', breaks = 1:6, 
                     labels = levels(test$test2), palette = 'Set3')
```

[image]

compare with not coercing  `..x..` to a factor

```
ggplot(test, aes(x= test2, group = test1)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..density.., fill = ..x..)) +
   facet_grid(~test1)
```

[image]

Comment: I love that Set3 pallete!

Comment: @mnel, I was trying to generate a similar bar plot in Shiny with position = "dodge", however getting all bars 100%. It would be great if you could suggest where I am going wrong. Thank you and sorry for getting in touch in this way. I have posted the question at      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078480/r-shiny-ggplot-bar-and-line-charts-with-dynamic-variable-selection-and-y-axis-to