# How to add percentage or count labels above percentage bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `ggplot2 1.0.0`, I followed the instructions in below post to figure out how to plot percentage bar plots across factors:

[Sum percentages for each facet - respect "fill"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236160/ggplot-sum-percentages-for-each-facet-respect-fill)

```
test <- data.frame(
     test1 = sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE), 
     test2 = sample(letters[3:8], 100, replace = TRUE)
     )
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(test, aes(x= test2, group = test1)) + 
geom_bar(aes(y = ..density.., fill = factor(..x..))) + 
facet_grid(~test1) +
scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

[image]

However, I cannot seem to get a label for either the total count or the percentage above each of the bar plots when using `geom_text`.

What is the correct addition to the above code that also preserves the percentage y-axis?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Staying within ggplot, you might try

```
ggplot(test, aes(x= test2,  group=test1)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..density.., fill = factor(..x..))) +
  geom_text(aes( label = format(100*..density.., digits=2, drop0trailing=TRUE),
                 y= ..density.. ), stat= "bin", vjust = -.5) +
  facet_grid(~test1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

For counts, change ..density.. to ..count.. in geom_bar and geom_text

**UPDATE for ggplot 2.x**

`ggplot2 2.0` made many changes to `ggplot` including one that broke the original version of this code when it changed the default `stat` function used by `geom_bar` [ggplot 2.0.0](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/12/21/ggplot2-2-0-0/).  Instead of calling `stat_bin`, as before, to bin the data, it now calls `stat_count` to count observations at each location.  `stat_count` returns `prop` as the proportion of the counts at that location rather than `density`.

The code below has been modified to work with this new release of `ggplot2`.  I've included two versions, both of which show the height of the bars as a percentage of counts.  The first displays the proportion of the count above the bar as a percent while the second shows the count above the bar.  I've also added labels for the y axis and legend.

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(scales)
#
# Displays bar heights as percents with percentages above bars
#
    ggplot(test, aes(x= test2,  group=test1)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
    geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
                   y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
    labs(y = "Percent", fill="test2") +
    facet_grid(~test1) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
#
# Displays bar heights as percents with counts above bars
#
    ggplot(test, aes(x= test2,  group=test1)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
    geom_text(aes(label = ..count.., y= ..prop..), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
    labs(y = "Percent", fill="test2") +
    facet_grid(~test1) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

The plot from the first version is shown below.

[image]

Comment: A good solution (+1)! Was trying to get the same but always forgot to include the damn `stat= "bin"` :-)

Comment: well played. That's nice and compact and contained.

Comment: It is.  In geom_text, y= ..density.. determines where the labels are placed.  You can assign any text string to label.  For counts,  just change label to label = ..count..

Comment: @WaltS Is it possible to have the Y axis remain density and the labels at the top of each bar be count without the entire axis shifting toward a count scale?

Comment: I am using R 3.3.0 and get this error: `Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?`

Comment: @arun Thanks for your comment.  The problem is due to changes which came with ggplot 2.0 .  I've posted an updated version which should work with ggplot 2.x releases.

Comment: @WaltS Thanks so much for taking the time to update. It works now!

Comment: @WaltS, I was trying to generate similar plot in Shiny with `position = "dodge"`, however getting all bars 100%. It would be great if you could suggest where I am going wrong. Thank you I have posted the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078480/r-shiny-ggplot-bar-and-line-charts-with-dynamic-variable-selection-and-y-axis-to

Comment: ggplot2_2.2.1 : use scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) instead.

Answer (score 15):

This is easier to do if you pre-summarize your data. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(25)
test <- data.frame(
  test1 = sample(letters[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE), 
  test2 = sample(letters[3:8], 100, replace = TRUE)
)

# Summarize to get counts and percentages
test.pct = test %>% group_by(test1, test2) %>%
  summarise(count=n()) %>%
  mutate(pct=count/sum(count)) 

ggplot(test.pct, aes(x=test2, y=pct, colour=test2, fill=test2)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ test1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent, limits=c(0,0.27)) + 
  geom_text(data=test.pct, aes(label=paste0(round(pct*100,1),"%"),
                               y=pct+0.012), size=4)
```

(FYI, you can put the labels inside the bar as well, for example, by changing the last line of code to this: `y=pct*0.5), size=4, colour="white")`)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've used all of your code and came up with this. First assign your ggplot to a variable i.e. p <- ggplot(...) + geom_bar(...) etc. Then you could do this. You don't need to summarize much since ggplot has a build function that gives you all of this already. I'll leave it to you for the formatting and such. Good luck.

```
    dat <- ggplot_build(p)$data %>% ldply() %>% select(group,density) %>% 
       do(data.frame(xval = rep(1:6, times = 2),test1 = mapvalues(.$group, from = c(1,2), to = c("a","b")), density = .$density))

    p + geom_text(data=dat, aes(x = xval, y = (density + .02), label = percent(density)), colour="black", size = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using    label = percent(..count..) in my solution but get an error message that it can't find function percent. It does find percent in facet_grid and it find format.  Any thoughts on why it can't find percent?

Comment: well I'm not sure. assuming you have the scales package loaded obviously. It sounds like a namespace masking issue to me. what you wrote above seems to me should have worked.

Comment: How did you change the factor labels from 1:6 to c:h?