# Change scale from count to percentage - ggplot2 version 1.0.1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried multiple solutions to this from previous versions of ggplot answers, however, I have yet to find a way to change the scale from count to percent.

The structure of the data includes: `deid` = an id variable; `variable` a one-level factor; and `value` = the participants response.

```
 $ deid     : int  123 155 332 224 654 325 865 654 555 434 ...
 $ variable : Factor w/ 1 level "tx.rating": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value    : int  9 8 9 9 5 7 7 7 7 10 ...
```

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(tx.plot, aes(value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = .6, binwidth = .5)
```

That creates:

[image]

I am hoping to get the percent responses from 0 - 10, not the count. I have tried to add `scale_y_continuous` and `scale_y_discrete` with the labels = percent command, however it has not worked and I receive error messages every time.

Comment: What if you calculate those percentages for each 0 to 10 value and save them as column `Prc` and then plot `value` and `Prc` in x an y axes? Some answers here might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869862/ggplot2-how-to-add-percentage-or-count-labels-above-percentage-bar-plot

Comment: Thanks, @AntoniosK, that is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
set.seed(1492)
tx.plot  <- data.frame(deid=sample(100:900, 50),
                       variable=factor(1),
                       value=sample(10, 50, replace=TRUE))
library(scales)
ggplot(tx.plot, aes(value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)), 
                 alpha = .6, binwidth = .5) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c(0,10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(label=percent) +
  labs(y="percent")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(tx.plot, aes(x = value)) + geom_density(aes(group=variable))
```