# How to add label to the bar plot using geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to put label in my plot I am getting error:

```
    ggplot(aes(x = factor(Pclass), fill = factor(Survived)), data = train) +
    geom_bar(color = "black", width = 0.30) +
    xlab("People Class") +
    ylab("Count")+
    geom_text(aes(label = factor(Survived)))

  Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

How can I add label without using y aesthetics or please correct if I am doing wrong. 
I am using Titanic train.csv data set [Titanic: Machine Learning from Disaster](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data)

Comment: Setting `stat = "identity"` in `geom_bar` requires a y aesthestic. As you don't have (and don't need) one, simply remove `stat = "identity"`.

Comment: Put the label inside first aes `ggplot(aes(..., label = factor(Survived))) + ... + geom_text()`

Comment: Sorry I was not using stat = "identity" in the code. By mistake I placed it here  @ottlngr

Comment: @zx8754  I have tried that one also but still the same error.

Comment: Then please provide data, so we can reproduce your error. Also, the error message is not complete, paste it in full.

Comment: Maybe try `ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(gear))) + geom_bar() + stat_count(aes(label = ..count..), geom = "text")` ?

Comment: See this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869862

Comment: Unfortunately that data link requires registration. Hopefully this is the same data, freely-available: https://github.com/pcsanwald/kaggle-titanic/blob/master/train.csv

Comment: Also: it's not clear what label you would like to add. Is it the total count of survived/not survived for each class?

Comment: @neilfws The registration at kaggle is also free and I want to label count.

Comment: @ShubhamRajput yes but you should not expect users to have to create accounts elsewhere in order to answer questions.

Comment: @neilfws Sure will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(gear))) +
geom_bar() + 
stat_count(aes(label = ..count..), geom = "text")
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is correct, but I think this is more consistent with the formatting you are using:

```
ggplot(aes(x = factor(Pclass), fill = factor(Survived)), data = train) +
  geom_bar(color = "black", width = 0.30) +
  xlab("People Class") +
  ylab("Count") +
  geom_text(aes(label=..count..), stat='count')
```