# ggplot2: adding labels to geom_bar() for a count

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to add count labels to my bar chart which is a simple frequency chart of the number of males and females in our study. I have tried + stat_count() and get the error - Error: stat_count requires the following missing aesthetics: x. I have also tried + geom_label(stat = "count"). Nothing seems to work. I can do this easily using excel, but I would like to do all my plots using R.

Does anyone have a simple solution for this?

My code:

```
`# Count of M vs F
sexfreq <- ggplot(data = BodyComp) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(SEX), width = .5, fill = "gray30") + 
  ggtitle ("Number of male and female participants") + 
  labs( x = "Sex", y = "Number of participants") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_grey()
sexfreq
```

`

It produces this:
[My plot without bar labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13SZf.png)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869862/how-to-add-percentage-or-count-labels-above-percentage-bar-plot

Comment: I don't think this is exactly a duplicate.  You need to have a data.frame with the total number for male and female.  Then add a `geom_text` line and set the `aes(text)` to the count of the participants.  If you post your data, I can show you.

Comment: Thank you Ben, but I've figured it out.