# Adding percentage labels to a barplot with y-axis 'count' in R

Tags: ggplot2, count, label, bar-chart, percentage

I'd like to add percentage labels per gear to the bars but keep the count y-scale.
E.g. 10% of all 'gear 3' are '4 cyl'

```
library(ggplot)

ds <- mtcars
ds$gear <- as.factor(ds$gear)

p1 <- ggplot(ds, aes(gear, fill=gear)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(cyl), margins=T) 

p1
```

[image]

Ideally only in ggplot, wihtout adding dplyr or tidy. I found some of these solutions but then I get other issues with my original data.

**EDIT:** Suggestions that this is a duplicate from:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869862/how-to-add-percentage-or-count-labels-above-percentage-bar-plot)

I saw this also earlier, but wasn't able to integrate that code into what I want:

```
# i just copy paste some of the code bits and try to reconstruct what I had earlier
ggplot(ds, aes(gear, fill=gear)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(cyl), margins=T) +       
  # ..prop.. meaning %, but i want to keep the y-axis as count
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +  
  # not sure why, but I only get 100% 
  geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
             y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that ggplot doesn't know that each facet is one group. [This very useful tutorial](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/miscellaneous-show-counts-and-percentages-for-bar-plots.html) helps with a nice solution. Just add `aes(group = 1)`

P.S. At the beginning, I was often quite reluctant and feared myself to manipulate my data and pre-calculate data frames for plotting. But there is no need to fret! It is actually often much easier (and safer!) to first shape / aggregate your data into the right form and then plot/ analyse the new data.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

ds <- mtcars
ds$gear <- as.factor(ds$gear)
```

First solution:

```r
ggplot(ds, aes(gear, fill = gear)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(cyl), margins = T) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), group = 1), stat= "count")
```

[image]

**edit** to reply to comment

Showing percentages across facets is quite confusing to the reader of the figure and I would probably recommend against such a visualization. You won't get around data manipulation here. The challenge is here to include your "facet margin". I create two summary data frames and bind them together.

```r
ds_count <- 
  ds %>% 
  count(cyl, gear) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(cyl = as.character(cyl))

ds_all <- 
  ds %>% 
  count(cyl, gear) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(n)) %>% 
  mutate(cyl = 'all', perc = 1)

ds_new <- bind_rows(ds_count, ds_all)

ggplot(ds_new, aes(gear, fill = gear)) +
    geom_col(aes(gear, n, fill = gear)) +
    facet_grid(cols = vars(cyl)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(perc)), stat= "count")
```

[image]

IMO, a better way would be to simply swap x and facetting variables. Then you can use ggplots summarising function as above.

```r
ggplot(ds, aes(as.character(cyl), fill = gear)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(gear), margins = T) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..), group = 1), stat= "count")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Nice and thanks, but unfortunately not yet what I am looking for.
Now when you sum e.g. the percent of red bars: 9+29+86 you get more than 100%.
Essentially I'd like to display how many % per gear are in one cyl, so that when summing up all same gear you get 100%.'