# r percentage by bin in histogram ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, percentage

I have a data set like this ->

```
library(ggplot2)

response <- c("Yes","No")
gend <- c("Female","Male")

purchase <- sample(response, 20, replace = TRUE)
gender <- sample(gend, 20, replace = TRUE)

df <- as.data.frame(purchase)
df <- cbind(df,gender)
```

so `head(df)` looks like this ->

```
  purchase gender
1      Yes Female
2       No   Male
3       No Female
4       No Female
5      Yes Female
6       No Female
```

Also, so you can validate my examples, here is `table(df)` for my particular sampling.
  *(please don't worry about matching my percentages)*

```
         gender
purchase Female Male
     No       6    3
     Yes      4    7
```

I want a "histogram" showing Gender, but split by Purchase.
I have gone this far ->

```
ggplot(df) + 
       geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),position = "dodge") + 
       aes(gender, fill = purchase)
```

which generates ->

histogram with split bins, by percentage, but not the aggregate level I want
[image: histogram with split bins, by percentage, but not the aggregate level I want]

The Y axis has Percentage as I want, but it has each bar of the chart as a percentage of the whole chart. 
What I want is the two "Female" bars to each be a percentage of there respective "Purchase". So in the chart above I would like four bars to be, 
`66%, 36%, 33%, 64%`
, in that order.

I have tried with geom_histogram to no avail. I have checked SO, searched, ggplot documentation, and several books.

Regarding the suggestion to look at the previous question about facets; that does work, but I had hoped to keep the chart visually as it is above, as opposed to split into "two charts". So...

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [percentage on y lab in a faceted ggplot barchart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725339/percentage-on-y-lab-in-a-faceted-ggplot-barchart)

Comment: @LoBu, thanks for the suggestion. The facets will work, and I can get by with that if I need to, but I was hoping to keep the chart "intact" as it looks in the question. But definitely thanks, because I'm going to use that if I can't get what I'm hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the percentages you want, is the denominator based on gender, or purchase? In the example given above, 66% for female & no purchase would be a result of 6 divided by the sum of no purchases (6+3) rather than the sum of all females (6+4).

It's definitely possible to plot that, but I'm not sure if the result would be intuitive to interpret. I got confused myself for a while.

The following hack makes use of the `weight` aesthetic. I've used purchase as the grouping variable here based on the expected output described in the question, though I think gender makes more sense (as per TTNK's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45744342/8449629) above):

```
df <- data.frame(purchase = c(rep("No", 6), rep("Yes", 4), rep("No", 3), rep("Yes", 7)),
                 gender = c(rep("Female", 10), rep("Male", 10)))

ggplot(df %>% 
         group_by(purchase) %>% #change this to gender if that's the intended denominator
         mutate(w = 1/n()) %>% ungroup()) + 
  aes(gender, fill = purchase, weight = w)+ 
  geom_bar(aes(x = gender, fill = purchase), position = "dodge")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "percent", labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: bar plot with weights]

Comment: I get this error when running your script    Error: n() should only be called in a data context

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
count(purchase, gender) %>% 
ungroup %>% 
group_by(gender) %>% 
mutate(prop = prop.table(n)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(gender, prop, group = purchase)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = purchase), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

The first 5 lines create a column `prop` (for "proportion"), which aggregates across `gender`.

To get there, you first `count` each `purchase` by `gender` (similar to the output of `table(df)`. Ungrouping then regrouping only by `gender` gives the aggregation we want.

Comment: Thanks @TTNK, that works great, but it feels like it should be possible entirely within GGPlot2. I'm trying to hone my ggplot skills so I'm hoping to find a definitive "it can" or "it can't" be done. I'll definitely remember this as a fall back. Or for times I just want to use base graphing.

Comment: @TTNK I have tried this and I get this error   Error: wt_var must be a single variable

Comment: @TTNK when I use the original posters data with your code I get this error    Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Yes' not found