# transform y axis to percents ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have used a stacked bar chart (with coord_flip) to try to compare distributions (this is one a several techniques I'm playing with) for a control and treatment group for pre and post test.  Here is the plot:

[image]

and here is the code (Sorry it's not reproducible with no data set.  If this is a problem I'll make up a reproducible data set as I can't share the real data):

```
m4 <- ggplot(data=v, aes(x=trt, fill=value))
m5 <- m4 +  geom_bar() + coord_flip() + 
      facet_grid(time~type) + scale_fill_grey()
```

How can I change the y axis (which is actually on the bottom dues to `coord_flip`) to percents so every bar is equal in length?  So I want counts to become percents. I need some sort of transformation that I'm betting ggplot has or could easily be created and applied some how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just want [position_fill](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/position_fill.html), by setting,

```
+ geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

Comment: That's it:  I was trying something like this [(LINK)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/ggplot-showing-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables) SO post but to no avail.  I'll mark it correct in 10 minutes as you're too quick.