# R: Faceted bar chart with percentages labels independent for each plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use facet_grid to produce several plots where each plot's percentage labels add to 100%.

In the image provided, the percentages labels add to 49% (first facet) and 51% (second facet).

I've seen [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567389/condition-a-count-summation-on-the-faceting-variable) where the solution is to aggregate the data outside ggplot.  I'd rather not do that, I believe this is a better approach.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10000, mean = 100, sd = 50))

df$factor_variable <- cut(df$x, right = TRUE, 
                          breaks = c(0, 25, 50, 100, 200, 10000),
                          labels = c("0 - 25", "26 - 50", "51 - 100", "101 - 200", "> 200")
                          )

df$second_factor_variable <- ifelse(df$x < 100, 1, 2)

df <- sample(df, x > 0)

table(df$second_factor_variable)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = factor_variable, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), ymax = 0.8))
p1 <- p1 + geom_bar(fill = "deepskyblue3", width=.5)
p1 <- p1 + stat_bin(geom = "text",
                    aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100), "%")),
                    vjust = -1, color = "grey30", size = 6)
p1 <- p1 + xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL)
p1 <- p1 + scale_y_continuous(label = percent_format())
p1 <- p1 + xlim("0 - 25", "26 - 50", "51 - 100", "101 - 200", "> 200")
p1 <- p1 + facet_grid(. ~ second_factor_variable)

print(p1)
```

[image: Here is the attempt]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method for the time being works. However the PANEL variable isn't documented and according to Hadley shouldn't be used. 
It seems the "correct" way it to aggregate the data and then plotting, there are many examples of this in SO.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor_variable, y = (..count..)/ sapply(PANEL, FUN=function(x) sum(count[PANEL == x])))) +
                 geom_bar(fill = "deepskyblue3", width=.5) +
                 stat_bin(geom = "text",
                          aes(label = paste(round((..count..)/ sapply(PANEL, FUN=function(x) sum(count[PANEL == x])) * 100), "%")),
                          vjust = -1, color = "grey30", size = 6) +
                 facet_grid(. ~ second_factor_variable)
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the PANEL variable documented?

Comment: @jlhoward Thanks for asking about the [panel variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622332/documentation-on-internal-variables-in-ggplot-esp-panel).

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but see Hadley Wickham's comments to my question [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/20622332/). BTW, I have no idea why your response was downrated; it certainly wasn't me.

Comment: @jilhoward Sure, i´ve seen the comment. The code outputs some warnings so it´s clearly not perfect... I was hoping there was a better method than just agreggating before plotting but this doesn´t seem to be posible.

Comment: I'm curious, since it's been 2+ years and a few ggplot2 iterations, is this still the recommended approach? ..PANEL.. hacks do seem hacky. Has this feature been requested? Stats and facets have always confused me, though.

Comment: It's not recommended to use `PANEL`! This is what the answer is saying. You should aggregate and then pas that to `ggplot`.