# ggplot2 with fill and group

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, grouping

I have problems filling the bars while grouping with facet_wrap
Using this data.frame:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(1234)
testDat <- data.frame(answer=factor(sample(c("yes", "no"), 60, replace=TRUE)),
                      which=factor(sample(c("q1", "q2", "q3"), 60, replace=TRUE)))
```

I wanted to plot the answer grouped by the variable which. This gives me the absolute values:

```
ggplot(testDat, aes(x=answer)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=answer)) + facet_wrap(~which)
```

This gives me the relative values. But not per group:

```
ggplot(testDat, aes(x=answer)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), fill=answer)) + facet_wrap(~which)
```

Searching for an answer I detected this to plot the relative values per group. But the fill color doesn't work anymore

```
ggplot(testDat, aes(x=answer)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), group=which, fill=answer)) + facet_wrap(~which)
```

It just works for the three different values of 'which' and not of 'answer'

```
ggplot(testDat, aes(x=answer)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), group=which, fill=which)) + facet_wrap(~which)
```

Any suggestions for how to fill the bars?

```
p1<-ggplot(testDat, aes(x=answer)) + geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), group=which, fill=answer)) + facet_wrap(~which)
p2<-ggplot(testDat, aes(x=answer)) + geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), group=which, fill=which)) + facet_wrap(~which)
grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

[image]

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df <- aggregate(answer~which,testDat,
                function(x)c(yes=sum(x=="yes")/length(x),no=sum(x=="no")/length(x)))
df <- data.frame(which=df$which, df$answer)
gg <- melt(df,id=1, variable.name="Answer",value.name="Rel.Pct.")
ggplot(gg) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Answer, y=Rel.Pct., fill=Answer),position="dodge",stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(~which)
```

Unfortunately, aggregating functions such as `sum(...), min(...), max(...), range(...)`, etc. etc., when used in aesthetic mappings, do not respect the grouping implied by facets. So, while `..count..` is subsetted properly when used alone (in your numerator), `sum(..count..)` gives the total for the whole dataset. This is why `(..count..)/sum(..count..)` gives the fraction of the *total*, not the fraction of the group.

The only way around that, that I am aware of, is to create an axillary table as above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation regarding the use of aggregating functions. I found a way around `..count../sum(..count..)` with `..density..)`. My question still remains why `fill=which` works and `fill=answer` doesn't.

Comment: Aggregating functions subset correctly for groups defined in aesthetic mappings (e.g, in the call to `aes(...)`). They do not work for groups defined implicitly in facets. So if you have `aes(..., fill=which)` and also `facet__wrap(~which)`, you are defining groups in both places and it will work. But that is a completely different plot.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to aggregate using ggplot as requested as [mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600900/r-faceted-bar-chart-with-percentages-labels-independent-for-each-plot).
However, it requires the use of the [PANEL variable that isn't documented therefore Hadley recomended not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622332/documentation-on-internal-variables-in-ggplot-esp-panel).

Here is a way to aggregate using `data.table`.
I've also added percentage labels to the plot.

```
grp <- function(x) {
  percentage = as.numeric(table(x)/length(x))
  list(x = levels(x),
       percentage = percentage,
       label = paste0( round( as.numeric(table(x)/length(x), 0 ) * 100 ), "%")
  )
}

require("data.table")
DT <- data.table(testDat)

# Simpler version
ggplot(DT[, grp(answer), by=which]) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=x, y=percentage, fill = x), position="dodge",stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(~which) + 
  xlab("Answer")

# With percentage labels and y axis with percentage
ggplot(DT[, grp(answer), by=which]) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=x, y=percentage, fill = x), position="dodge",stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(x=x, ymax = 0.6, y=percentage, label = label), vjust = -1.2, color = "grey20") +
  facet_grid(~which) + 
  xlab("Answer") + xlim("yes", "no") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Answer")
```

[image]