# In ggplot2, how can I make a bar chart of proportions across factors (and add error bars)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling with making a graph of proportion of a variable across a factor in ggplot.

Taking `mtcars` data as an example and stealing part of a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/ggplot-showing-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables) I can come up with

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl))) +  
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

This graph gives me proportion of each `cyl` category in the whole dataset.

What I'd like to get though is the proportion of cars in each `cyl` category, that have automatic transmission (binary variable `am`).

On top of each bar I would like to add an error bar for the proportion.

Is it possible to do it with `ggplot` only? Or do I have to first prepare a data frame with summaries and use it with `identity` option of bar graphs?

I found some examples on [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_%28ggplot2%29/#bar-graphs) web page, but they deal with continuous y variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that it would be easier to make new data frame and then use it for plotting. Here I calculated proportions and lower/upper confidence interval values (took them from `prop.test()` result).

```
library(plyr)
mt.new<-ddply(mtcars,.(cyl),summarise,
      prop=sum(am)/length(am),
      low=prop.test(sum(am),length(am))$conf.int[1],
      upper=prop.test(sum(am),length(am))$conf.int[2])

ggplot(mt.new,aes(as.factor(cyl),y=prop,ymin=low,ymax=upper))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked as a charm!