# Plotting proportions within a scaling with geom_bar

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am having an issue with creating a bar graph of proportions.

This is my current code:

```
ggplot(data = d,
       aes(fill = version)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom') +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cregion,
               y = ..count../sum(..count..)),
           position = 'dodge') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Which produces this:
[image: derp-plot]

This scales the bars so that the total sum is 100%, however. What I want is for the salmon bars to sum to 100%, and also for the aqua bars to sum to 100%. In other words, I am interested in the proportions *within* the scaling. Is there a way to do this with ggplot besides just going into my data and mucking around with my variables?

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2017, with ggplot2 2.2.1 I think the best solution is explained in Hadley Wickham's R for data science book:

```
ggplot(data = d,aes(x=cregion)) + 
stat_count(aes(y=..prop.., group=version, fill = version, position = "dodge"))+
theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
coord_flip()
```

stat_count computes two variables: count is used by default, but you can choose to use prop which shows proportions.

Find the original answer at 
[Show % instead of counts in charts of categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables)