# ggplot histogram with % and percentage *labels*

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, histogram

I want to use ggplot to make a histogram using percentages. I found **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/ggplot-showing-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables)** that gets me part of the way there.

However, I also want to place a **label at the top of each histogram bar** showing the actual percentage.

Here is my code and a link to the output:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp)) +  
        geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth = 25) + 
        ## scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) #version 3.0.9
        scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) #version 3.1.0
p <- p + stat_bin(aes(label=round((..count..)/sum(..count..),2)), geom="text", size=4)
plot(p)
```

Here is the output: [image]

Unfortunately, you can see that the data labels are placed at the non-percentage locations and the bars are "smushed" down.

Is there a way to change the stat_bin parameters so that the text labels actually show up inside or immediately on top of the percentage bars (so that my bars aren't smushed)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to just set the `y` values for your labels as well (and also make sure you're using the same bins are you are for the bars)

```
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp)) +  
        geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth = 25) + 
        scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) #version 3.0.9
        ##scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) #version 3.1.0
p <- p + stat_bin(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), 
    label=round((..count..)/sum(..count..),2)), 
    geom="text", size=4, binwidth = 25, vjust=-1.5)
plot(p)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I didn't realize you could specify the y value in addition to the label value. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When using `geom_bar()` with `binwidth` you will currently get following error:

> `geom_bar()` no longer has a `binwidth` parameter. Please use
>   `geom_histogram()` instead.

I modified MrFlick's code by including `geom_histogram()` and by displaying the values to be shown as percentage (instead of fractions) using `paste0` function.

```
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp)) +  
  geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), binwidth = 25) +
      stat_bin(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..), 
             label=paste0(round((..count..)/sum(..count..)*100,1),"%")), 
             geom="text", size=4, binwidth = 25, vjust=-1.5)
plot(p)
```

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3JvL.png)