# geom_text works for histogram in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Wondering if `geom_text` works for `hist`? Tried following code and it seems no effect. I just want to show label (the number of elements belonging to a specific histogram bucket), when plotting each bar for each histogram bucket. Any solutions are appreciated. Thanks.

```
p <- hist(df$foo,
          main="title",xlab="foo")
p + geom_text()
```

**Edit 1**, tried `geom_bar`, here is my code and it seems not working well, since I expect a number labelled on each bar. In the diagram, it only shows 2.5, 5, 7.5 and 10, I expect to show 1, 2, 3, ..., 9, 10 for each bar.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(df$foo))
g + geom_bar()
```

[image]

regards,
Lin

Comment: Check out `geom_bar` from the `ggplot2` package. `geom_text` and `hist` are not mean to be used together.

Comment: @MikeyMike, thanks, wondering if any solution if I use `hist`?

Comment: @MikeyMike, updated my code example, it seems `geom_bar ` does not work good for my example. Vote up and your advice is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate (if you want a histogram): http://stackoverflow.com/q/27593888/903061

Comment: Possible dupe for the bar plot: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29869862/903061

Comment: I think @Gregor's first comment is what you wanted.

Comment: @Gregor, thanks and vote up. I read the first post, and confused by what means `aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)`, especially what means `..count..`? Tried to find help in R but failed. If you could comment, it will be great.

Comment: @shayaa, vote up for the reply. I read the first sample, and confused by what means `aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)`, especially what means `..count..`? Tried to find help in R (by `? ..count..`) but failed. If you could comment, it will be great.

Comment: @Gregor, for the 2nd example, I tried and it works, but confused by statement `aes(x= test2,  group=test1))`, in R help, I do not find for `aes`, there is a parameter called `group`, could you elaborate what `group` means? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since no one has answered this I'll give it a try:

First, a few tips:

- posting your data will make it more likely for people to answer (so we don't have to replicate it)
- Doing some research on your own goes a long way. For example, you mention that you want a label for each bar - fine there are several ways to do it. A quick google search digs up this: [Customize axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096538/customizing-the-axis-labels-in-ggplot)

Now to actually answer your question:

```
set.seed(1)
#Make sample data since none is provided
df <- data.frame(foo=sample(1:10,200,replace=T))

#This is what you want - use as.factor(foo) - this gives you the breaks at every bar.
g <- ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(foo)))

#Actually making the barplot and adding labels to it
g + geom_bar() +stat_count(aes(y=..count..,label=..count..),geom="text",vjust=-1)
```

[image]

To your question about `..count..` see: [Special variables in ggplot (..count.., ..density.., etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570293/special-variables-in-ggplot-count-density-etc).

Comment: Thanks MikeyMike, vote up and mark your reply as answer.