# ggplot2: how to plot proportional stacked bar graph with counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

Currently my code below plots the count of cases stratified by `columnB` and over different years on the x-axis. Instead of actual counts, I would like to plot the proportions of cases. How would I go about and do that?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= year, fill=columnB)) + geom_bar()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot: showing % instead of counts in charts of categorical variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/ggplot-showing-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by adding

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= year, fill=columnB)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

You can refer [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/position_fill.html)

Just modify the answer. Thanks Heroka for pointing out the error of my previous answer.

Comment: Are you sure this works? Doesn't stat=identity need a variable mapped to the y-axis?

Comment: Of course it works. If you would like to use explicit mapping, you can rewrite the code as  `ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x= year, fill=columnB), stat = "identity")`. You can either write **aes** part in **ggplot()** or in **geom_bar()** because ggplot2 grammar is kind of layer structure, probably you can compare it with photoshop graph layers.

Comment: That's not what I meant at all. I was trying to be polite, but please consider the following code: `df <- data.frame(year=factor(rep(2000:2003, each=5)),
                  columnB=sample(LETTERS[1:5],20,T)); ggplot(df, aes(x = year, fill = columnB)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`. You will get an error.

Comment: @Heroka Oh, Okay. In this case, should use `position = 'fill'` rather than `stat = 'identity'`. Thanks for pointing this out!