# ggplot2: geom_bar, computing facet-wise percentage

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use the `geo_bar` with facets, obtaining percentage instead of absolute counts, but percentage should be relative to each facet, not relative to the overall count.

This has been discussed a lot ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables)), suggesting to use `geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))`. This won't work with facets (i.e. will give total count). A better solution has been suggested, 
using `stat_count(mapping = aes(x=x_val, y=..prop..))` instead.

This seems to work if `x` is *numeric*, but not if `x` is *character*: all bars are 100%! Why? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(val_num = c(rep(1, 60), rep(2, 40), rep(1, 30), rep(2, 70)),
             val_cat = ifelse(val_num==1, "cat", "mouse"),
             group=rep(c("A", "B"), each=100))

#works with numeric 
ggplot(df) + stat_count(mapping = aes(x=val_num, y=..prop..)) + facet_grid(group~.)

# does not work? 
ggplot(df) + stat_count(mapping = aes(x=val_cat, y=..prop..)) + facet_grid(group~.)
```

Comment: If your x-axis is category, you're essentially asking "which percentage of cats are cats and which percentage of mice are mice?"

Comment: I think the question is within group/facet A, what's the proportion of cats (or values 1) vs mice (value 2). And same for group B, no? But yes, maybe my question is ill-posed? I still don't see why the behaviour is different for numeric than character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `group=group` tells ggplot to calculate proportions by `group`, rather than the default, which would be separately for each level of `val_cat`.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  stat_count(aes(x=val_cat, y=..prop.., group=group)) + 
  facet_grid(group~.)
```

[image]

When the x-variable is continuous, it looks like `stat_count` by default calculates percentages over all data in the facet. However, when the x-variable is categorical, `stat_count` calculates percentages separately within each x level. See what happens with the following examples:

Adding `val_num` as the group aesthetic causes percentages to be calculated within each x level instead of over all values in a facet.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  stat_count(aes(x=val_num, y=..prop.., group=val_num)) + 
  facet_grid(group~.)
```

Turning `val_num` into a factor likewise causes percentages to be calculated within each x level instead of over all values in a facet.

```
ggplot(df) + 
  stat_count(aes(x=factor(val_num), y=..prop..)) + 
  facet_grid(group~.)
```

Comment: great, well spotted! it's interesting to note that you need to specify the `group` for character values, not for numeric ones.

Comment: Yes. Character values represent separate categories and are by default therefore treated as separate groups. On the other hand, numeric values typically represent measurements of some population or process, or time and are treated as elements of a single group. That's why `geom_line` connects points across x values when the x-axis is numeric (all the measurements are within a single group) but not when the x-axis is categorical (each x-axis value is a different group). Same for why color and fill is a gradient for numeric values but separate colors for categorical values.