# How to create a histogram with fixed bin width on percentage scale reflective for each facet?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I would like to create a histogram where the y-axis shows the percentage per facet in ggplot2. I have seen several similar questions but some answers seem outdated or they show the percentage of all observations rather than per facet.

I tried this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg))+
    facet_grid(cyl ~ am)+
    stat_count(aes(y=..prop..)) +
    theme_bw()+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

Which seems to work, except that the binwidth is not fixed. Facets with few observations have large bars.

How could I fix the binwidth?

EDIT: Solution adapted from [ACNB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables) 
I overlooked that before and I just saw that Andrey Kolyadin was quicker to provide a more concise solution.

```
binwidth <- 1
mtcars.stats <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl, am) %>%
    mutate(bin = cut(mpg, breaks=seq(0,35, binwidth), 
                     labels = seq(0 + binwidth, 35, binwidth)-(binwidth/2)),
           n = n()) %>%
    group_by(cyl, am, bin) %>%
    summarise(p = n()/n[1]) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(bin = as.numeric(as.character(bin)))

ggplot(mtcars.stats, aes(x = bin, y= p)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    facet_grid(cyl~am)+
    theme_bw()+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

Comment: I did something similar a few weeks ago and found it easier to use `gridExtra` instead of `facet_grid` to set stuff like binwidth individually.

Comment: `stat_count(aes(y = ..prop..), width = 1)`

Comment: Do I have to worry about this warning `position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alway I advice not to rely on statistics layer of `ggplot2` and calculate necessary statistics before plotting:

```
library('zoo')
library('tidyverse')

# Selecting breaks
breaks <- seq.int(min(mtcars$mpg), max(mtcars$mpg), length.out = 19)

# Calculating densities
mt_hist <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  summarise(x = list(rollmean(breaks, 2)),
            count = list(hist(mpg, breaks = breaks, plot = FALSE)$counts)) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  mutate(count = count/sum(count))
```

And plot itself:

```
ggplot(mt_hist)+
  aes(x = x,
      y = count)+
  geom_col()+
  facet_grid(cyl ~ am)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

[image]

Comment: Good call, I was going to reply but you've done a much better solution - great advice too, to do a bit of data munging beforehand rather than the ggplot stats layer (which is what I was attempting!)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding the `geom_histogram` and `stat` argument, something like ...

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg))
p <- p + geom_histogram(stat = 'bin')
p <- p + facet_grid(cyl ~ am)
p <- p + stat_count(aes(y=..prop..))
p <- p +   theme_bw()
p <- p +   scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
p
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems not quite correct. The percentages go beyond 100.