# ggplot: How to add a certain percentage to the top of the pillars of a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis

I need to replicate a certain format of a histogram/barchart. I already did some good modification with `ggplot`  in order to group the categorial x-variable and specifiy the colors with HEX.

Here is what I try to plot/replicate:

[image]

Here is a MWE for my data structure:

```
sex <- sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE)
group <- sample(2:5, 100, replace=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(sex, group)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = group, group=sex, fill=factor(sex) )) +
  geom_histogram(position="dodge", binwidth=0.45) +                      
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank()) +    
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="sex")) +                        
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())   +              
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#b6181f", "#f6b8bb"))
```

I get:

[image]

Small things I can't handle are:

- replace the factor labels on the x-axis, there might be a problem with my histogram-approach, but I also found no practical way with a bar-chart
- round the percentage-digits, no decimals for percentages

But most important is, that I don't know how to add a single percentage-value for one group, one sex to the top of each bar..

I am looking forward for some advice :)

Comment: Ok, sorry for this. The initial problem is solved :)

Comment: Alright I have rollbacked your edits, but you can still see the other versions by clicking on the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48113765/revisions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would treat your x-axis data as factors and plot it as bars. Getting percentage value text to the bar top look this question: [Show % instead of counts in charts of categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables).
Futhermore the y-axis percent values aren't a question of rounding, they actually are no percentage values. `y = ..prop..` solves that.

Are you looking for that (I summed everything up)?

```
sex <- sample(0:1, 100, replace=TRUE)
group <- sample(2:5, 100, replace=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(sex, group)

labs <- c("Score < 7", "Score\n7 bis < 12", "Score\n12 bis < 15",
          "Score\n15 bis < 20","Score >= 20")

ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(group), y = ..prop.., group = sex, fill = factor(sex) )) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..)), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), stat = "count", vjust = 2) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "sex")) +                        
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())   +              
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#b6181f", "#f6b8bb")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labs)
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer! Here's some possible adjustments: you can use `..prop..` instead of `..count.. / sum(..count..)`. Using `vjust = 2` would put the labels in the bars. `position_dodge(width = 0.9)` puts the text in the middle of the bars. (And maybe use some line breaks to avoid code running off screen.)

Comment: Wow great, I just not realized that the exact replication lacks the problem that percentages are reported twice and don't add information. Is it possible to either add the absolute number of obs to y-axis or the pillars? Regards

Comment: @Marco Just change the `label` in `geom_text` to `label = ..count..` and you get absolute count values