# How can I add a percentage label to the bars in this chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a chart (it started out as a histogram but I changed it to a bar chart so that I could use percentages more easily):

[image]

This is the code for the chart:

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.Date(callclosed), y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
      geom_bar(fill = "skyblue1",
               colour = "black") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 0.06)) +
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day", date_labels = "%d-%b-%y") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

How can I add labels to the top of each bar that shows the associated percentage?

Comment: Try this `geom_text(aes( label = format(100*..density.., digits=2, drop0trailing=TRUE),
                 y= ..density.. ), stat= "bin", vjust = -.5) +`      OR        `geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
                   y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5)`

Comment: In above dup question, see [@SamFirke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35067032/1422451).