# How do I use the stat()-command with categorical data in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is about converting the Y-values in your plot to percentages, much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables). However, the answers no longer seem applicable since [we can no longer surround our variables with ".."](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat.html), but have to use the stat()-function.

My plot looks like this:

[image]

It's created with the following code. The X-variable is a categorical variable (city) and the y variable counts the number of observation for each city:

```
ggplot(fulldata, aes(x=fct_rev(fct_infreq(CITY_LADOK)))) +geom_bar() +coord_flip()
```

I want to transform the y valuables to percentages, preferably without having to create a reference table. The help page for calculated aesthetics is....not particularly helpful. It doesn't state if percentages can be calculated nor how it's done. If I extrapolate from the examples though, I should be able to write something along the lines of:

```
    ggplot(fulldata, aes(x=fct_rev(fct_infreq(CITY_LADOK)))) 
+geom_bar(y=stat(count/sum(count)))+coord_flip()
```

...In theory at least, now I get an error message claiming:

```
Error in sum(count) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument
```

But what if I scale this down and simply use stat() to calculate the original plot?

```
ggplot(fulldata, aes(x=fct_rev(fct_infreq(CITY_LADOK)))) 
    +geom_bar(y=stat(count))+coord_flip()
```

We get another error message

```
Error in rep(value[[k]], length.out = n) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

It doesn't work with y=stat(bin) and it doesn't seem to work with y=stat(identity) either. Can the stat()-function be used *at all* with categorical values and if so, can it be used to calculate percentages?

Excerpt of data:

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 
17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776, 17776), class = "Date"), 
    CITY_LADOK = c("GÖTEBORG", "LILLA_EDET", "GÖTEBORG", "GÖTEBORG", 
    "UDDEVALLA", "SKÖVDE", "VÄSTERÅS", "TROLLHÄTTAN", "ALE", 
    "GÖTEBORG", "GÖTEBORG", "GÖTEBORG", "UPPSALA", "TJÖRN", "TROLLHÄTTAN", 
    "UDDEVALLA", "UDDEVALLA", "KUNGSBACKA", "VÄNERSBORG", "UDDEVALLA"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(start_date = structure(17776, class = "Date"), 
    .rows = list(1:20)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnus, you're quite close, but you'll want to ensure you're using the `aes()` function carefully when you map a variable to an aesthetic. Basically, any time you have a dynamic value that you're providing to a ggplot function, `aes()` is required. Small sample below.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  city = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 2), "C", "D", "E")
)

# Simplified count will work, but make sure to use aes()
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(city)))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = stat(count))) +
  coord_flip()

# Percentage will work as well, but take care with aes() and parentheses
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(city)))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = stat(count) / sum(stat(count)))) +
  coord_flip()

# Can also request the proportion directly, but then need to ensure 
# proportion grouping isn't the x variable by default.
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(city)))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = stat(prop), group = NA)) +
  coord_flip()
```

You might also want to note that `stat()` accesses computed variables -- things like `count` or `prop` in the case of `geom_bar(), geom_col()`. The family of `stat_identity(), stat_count(), stat_bin()` are different, and describe different ways for ggplot to aggregate the data.

Comment: Thank you for your pedagogical (is that an expression?) answer. I'm a bit uncertain of what a "dynamic value" entails, but what I take home from this is that (1) in order to access variables inside geoms i first need to use the aes()-function and (2), I can't use calculated values directly, but need to use the stat()-function prior to each separate use.

Comment: Yep. If instead you were providing something simple static like `color = "blue"` as an argument to `geom_bar`, you wouldn't need to wrap it in `aes()`.