# Percentage instead of count in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, bar-chart, percentage

I'm just beggining with programming.
I have this data frame:

```
data1 = data.frame(NSE=c("A-B", "C", "D-E"), Percentage=c(68, 66, 63))
```

And I made this barplot:

```
a = ggplot(data1, aes(x=NSE, y=Percentage))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.6, fill = "red", color = "grey40", alpha = 5)+ 
geom_text(aes(label=Percentage), vjust=1.5, color="white", 
size=3)+
ggtitle("No se sintieron discriminados en los últimos 
doce meses, según NSE (en porcentaje)")+labs(y="", x="")+
theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=10, face="bold"))+ylim(0,100)
```

It creates three bars corresponding to values 68, 66 and 63. But I want the bars to show these values as percentages (68%, 66%, 63%). What should I do to get the that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show % instead of counts in charts of categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `scales::percent` and `scales::percent_format` this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

data1 = data.frame(NSE=c("A-B", "C", "D-E"), Percentage=c(68, 66, 63))

ggplot(data1, aes(x=NSE, y=Percentage))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.6, fill = "red", color = "grey40", alpha = 5)+ 
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(Percentage, scale = 1, accuracy = 1)), vjust=1.5, color="white", 
            size=3)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1, accuracy = 1), limits = c(0,100)) +
  ggtitle("No se sintieron discriminados en los ultimos 
doce meses, segun NSE (en porcentaje)")+labs(y="", x="")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=10, face="bold"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Without using the `scales` package one could simply use

```
function(x) paste0(round(x*100), "%)
```

in the `label` aesthetic of `geom_text`, as follows:

```
+ geom_text(aes(label=paste0(round(Percentage), "%")), vjust=1.5, color="white", 
size=3)
```

Additionally, in the `labels` argument of `scale_y_continuous` one could do the same, like so

```
+ scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(round(x), "%"))
```