# How to convert normal barplot to a percentage barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Kindly help me convert this to a percentage barplot using ggplot2. I have tried a few ways but the percentage values don't come right. I also wanted to place the numerical value of percentages on top of each barplot.

```r
g<-read.csv("survey.csv")
data<-g

data$Number.of.Beetle <- trimws(data$Number.of.Beetle)
lvls <- unique(data$Number.of.Beetle)
lvls <- stringr::str_sort(lvls, numeric = TRUE)
data$Number.of.Beetle <- factor(data$Number.of.Beetle, levels = lvls)

 lvls2 <- unique(data$Building.Age)
lvls2 <- lvls2[c(2, 3, 1)]
data$Building.Age <- factor(data$Building.Age, levels = lvls2)

 ggplot(data, aes(x = Locality.Division))+
   geom_bar(aes(fill = Number.of.Beetle), position = "dodge")+
   facet_wrap(~ Building.Age) +
   labs(title = "Comparison between Number of beetle, Locality division and Age of the building",subtitle ="Building age")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Does this question have answers that help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3695497/3358272

Comment: If those answers don't resolve it for you, please make your question reproducible by including sample/representative data. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a proportion in the `aes` of `geom_bar`.

```
library(scales)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Locality.Division))+
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill = Number.of.Beetle), position = "dodge")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  ylab("relative frequencies") +
  facet_wrap(~ Building.Age) +
  labs(title = "Comparison between Number of beetle, Locality division and Age of the building",subtitle ="Building age")
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you also help me place the percentage labels on top of each bar? I tried using the geom text function but then it turns to ba an error

Comment: You can do something like: geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = -0.25)

Comment: This is actually modifying the plot. I am getting the combined percentages under all three categories. But I was looking for a separate percentage label on each bar under each category. Could you please suggest changes