# Plot a % of a dataset in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a population category inside the whole population.

So if I have:

```
df <- data.frame (population= c("a", "a", "a", "a","b", "b","b","b","c","c"),
              income= c("10", "15", "12", "19","45", "42","41","43","23","23")
              )
```

How can I plot the proportion of "a" from the whole `df` in a density plot? Like in the following picture:

[image]

### EDIT

What I am trying to plot is the density of the values a, b and c. Not the income values. And inside this density plot, I want to shadow only the 'a' values.
Basically, I want to shadow in a density plot the proportion of a value from a dataframe column.

This is the link of the dataset I am working on. I want to plot the proportion of the value "Self-Employed" in the "workclass" variable.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What kind of plot do you want?

Comment: I need a density one.

Comment: The plot you show is not a density plot of a, b, and c, it's a proportion of a Normal distribution. BTW, your "data" is all strings? Normally one would work with numbers as ... numbers (`integer` or `numeric`). I suggest you are not far enough into your data munging to be able to ask about plots if you don't even have numeric data.

Comment: I understand what you say, but my file data is over 30k rows and it has categories, where it actually has a workclass column. Inside it has 4 different string categories and I want to plot the percentage of one of them. That's why I am asking this, I already know I can plot the numeric ones.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear indeed. But maybe you meant something like this

```
hist(as.numeric(df[df$population=='a','income']), freq = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a link in [S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-percent-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables). This is my final code:

```
ggplot(censo, aes(x = factor(workclass))) +  
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```